# Why do I get an IOException: CRC Mismatch on Android 2.3 devices and not 2.2 while parsing json from a URL?

Tags: java, android, ioexception

What I'm trying to do is get some json results back from a URL using a Bufferedreader which uses a inputstreamreader. I read each line and for each JSONObject i get properties and do awesome things with them later.

Anyway, on Android 2.2 the code works fine but when i test on a 2.3 device (emulated, stock, or custom rom alike) i get this exception:

```
06-22 15:33:13.958: ERROR/App(416): IOException
06-22 15:33:13.958: ERROR/App(416): java.io.IOException: CRC mismatch
06-22 15:33:13.958: ERROR/App(416):     at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.verifyCrc(GZIPInputStream.java:201)
06-22 15:33:13.958: ERROR/App(416):     at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(GZIPInputStream.java:184)
06-22 15:33:13.958: ERROR/App(416):     at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:255)
06-22 15:33:13.958: ERROR/App(416):     at java.io.BufferedReader.fillBuf(BufferedReader.java:128)
06-22 15:33:13.958: ERROR/App(416):     at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:357)
06-22 15:33:13.958: ERROR/App(416):     at ca.bnotions.App.Places.fetchData(Places.java:57)
06-22 15:33:13.958: ERROR/App(416):     at ca.bnotions.App.Places.onCreate(Places.java:40)
06-22 15:33:13.958: ERROR/App(416):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-22 15:33:13.958: ERROR/App(416):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
06-22 15:33:13.958: ERROR/App(416):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
06-22 15:33:13.958: ERROR/App(416):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-22 15:33:13.958: ERROR/App(416):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
06-22 15:33:13.958: ERROR/App(416):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-22 15:33:13.958: ERROR/App(416):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-22 15:33:13.958: ERROR/App(416):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-22 15:33:13.958: ERROR/App(416):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-22 15:33:13.958: ERROR/App(416):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-22 15:33:13.958: ERROR/App(416):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-22 15:33:13.958: ERROR/App(416):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-22 15:33:13.958: ERROR/App(416):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
public ArrayList<String> fetchData()
    {
        list_items = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            URL places_data = new URL("http://myurl.com");
            URLConnection tc = places_data.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(tc.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(line);

                for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                    list_items.add(jo.getString("name"));
                }
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e("MyApp","MalformedURLException",e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("MyApp","IOException",e);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("MyApp","JSONException",e);
        }

        return list_items;
    }
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Marcus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have time to research this to understand why it doesn't work and why you are getting the error. But I do have time to show you how I do it which works great.

Download the Apache Mime and Commons HttpClient Jar libraries and add them to your project's Java Build Path.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
request.setURI(new URI("http://www.codinggreenrobots.com"));

HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
String line = "";
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line + "\n";
}
in.close();
str_response = sb.toString();
```

Now that you have parsed the response, just turn it in a JSONObject.

```
JSONObject event_object = new JSONObject(str_response);
```

I hope that works for you as well as it works for me.